# AntD RangePicker appearing behind Material UI dialog in my ReactJS web app - how to fix?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, material-ui, antd

my website have rangepicker from ant-d and teg dialog from materialUI and when I click on rangepicker my calendar behind dialog, I attached image

```
import {DatePicker} from "antd";
import {
    Dialog,
    DialogActions,
    DialogContent,
    DialogContentText,
    DialogTitle,} from "@mui/material"

<Dialog
    open={open}
    onClose={handleClose}
    aria-labelledby="scroll-dialog-title"
    aria-describedby="scroll-dialog-description"
            >
                <DialogTitle id="scroll-dialog-title">Оновити дані про транспортний засіб</DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent>
                    <DialogContentText
                        id="scroll-dialog-description"
                        ref={descriptionElementRef}
                        tabIndex={-1}
                        sx={{paddingTop: '20px'}}
                    >
                           <RangePicker
                                name="dates"
                                value={values.dates}
                                onChange={(dates) => setFieldValue('dates', dates)}
                            />
</DialogContentText>
                </DialogContent>
                <DialogActions>
                    <Button onClick={handleClose}>Відмінити</Button>
                    <Button onClick={handleSubmit}>Оновити дані</Button>
                </DialogActions>
            </Dialog>
```

I need to fix it, i want my rangepicker was above this all. This I attached my image.[image]

Comment: The drawer has a `z-index` of 1200.  It appears that the antd picker presentation layer is lower than this.  Can you verify the `z-index` of the antd presentation layer?

Comment: i can't verify it